Why would a Tomcat 8.5 Connection Pool with Oracle have unused open (Dead?) connections?
I have a Grails 2.5 application that is deployed to Tomcat 8.5 application server where one customer is reporting that they are running out of connections in the connection pool. As part of the diagnostics for this their DBA is running a query against v$session and saying there are 'dead' (DBA's words), unused connections that are never being used from the pool. They are using the PREV_SQL_ID column as being null to make this determination.
I have not seen this scenario internally in any dev or test environments that I have access too.
My question is, is this a valid use of the PREV_SQL_ID column? What does it mean, should it be null?
I will say that the application is very heavy in its database use and so I would expect all initial connections in the pool to be used at least once. Ceratinly after the application has been up and running for a while
Reference Info:
JDBC URL is vanila, ie: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server.org:1522/service_name'
Tomcat Pool Configuration (from Datasource.groovy):
            properties {
                jmxEnabled = true
                initialSize = 5
                minIdle = 5
                maxIdle = 25
                maxWait = 10000
                maxAge = 10 * 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                validationQueryTimeout = 3
                validationInterval = 15000
                testOnBorrow = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                testOnReturn = false
                jdbcInterceptors = 'ConnectionState'
                defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

                validationQuery = 'select 1 from dual'

                maxActive = 50
            }

Results on customer system from a select on v$session for the connection pool user (I have more data from the query but have abbreviated it here for readability):



SID
Machine
Login
Prev exec start
PREV_SQL_ID
LAST_CALL_ET




412
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
8p7uxtbaga5gt
0


4055
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
adg3hxn57syna
3


10712
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


9512
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5xmx4tywy26y6
14


1638
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


11126
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
adg3hxn57syna
0


1638
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:10 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
14


5873
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:10 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


2034
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:10 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
cdmran58d6r3t
11


1229
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:10 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
11


5264
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:10 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
10


10326
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:09 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
5xmx4tywy26y6
14


5882
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:08 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
10


815
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:07 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


1625
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:07 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


4453
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:07 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
14


4867
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:05 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


9101
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:05 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


2853
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:04 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
14


5276
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:02 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


4465
Xyz
5/6/2024 6:01 PM
5/6/2024 6:11 PM
520mkxqpf15q8
9


11119
Xyz
5/5/2024 10:52 AM
5/5/2024 10:54 AM

112624


11123
Xyz
5/4/2024 6:56 PM
5/4/2024 7:00 PM

169871


3664
Xyz
5/4/2024 12:18 PM
5/4/2024 12:19 PM

193926


7090
Xyz
5/3/2024 7:20 PM
5/3/2024 7:22 PM

254946


2448
Xyz
5/3/2024 5:38 PM
5/3/2024 5:43 PM

260858


3236
Xyz
5/3/2024 5:34 PM
5/3/2024 5:40 PM

261039


3642
Xyz
5/3/2024 5:13 PM
5/3/2024 5:17 PM

262431


7496
Xyz
5/3/2024 5:01 PM
5/3/2024 5:02 PM

263344


1644
Xyz
5/3/2024 4:14 PM
5/3/2024 4:16 PM

266088


2027
Xyz
5/3/2024 4:14 PM
5/3/2024 4:14 PM

266225



My Investigationt
I can't find any references in my own searching as to the meaning of the PREV_SQL_ID column and how it might behave with respect to connection pooling.
My understanding is that if there is a problem with the connection, the validation query will fail and so the connection is removed from the pool.
I've reviewed the Tomcat documentation regarding abandoned connections. These connections appear to have never been used, so could they still be considered abandoned? How could I determine/log if that is the case?
Based on comment from Paul W - I've added last_call_et to the table of data from v$session. Does seem like those connections are not being used.

No, that is not a correct use of prev_sql_id (internally, x$ksuse.ksusepsi). In most cases it does mean that the session (if a USER type session that is not a parallel slave nor a job process) has not issued a second SQL and it's uncommon to find these session with NULL values.
However, a "dead"/orphaned connection in DBA-speak is a session no longer being controlled by the initiating client layer. There's no way to tell from the database side that this is the case, except for the suggestive evidence of an idle session with a very high value (e.g. many days worth) in last_call_et. That is much more meaningful than a NULL in prev_sql_id.

Thanks for the feedback Paul. I've added the LAST_CALL_ET column to my table above. It does appear to correlate with the PREV_SQL_ID column

@JohnLear, If you have a bunch of idle sessions with high LAST_CALL_ET values, kill them. Write a DBA-owned proc, schedule it and have it kick those orphaned sessions off. We do that in our org.

I don't know how the Tomcat pool works, but a reasonable thing to do is to reuse the most recently returned connection. Connections are associated with OS processes on the database. Using a recently used connection keeps the associated database OS process warm while allowing the system to recover cached resources supporting less recently used OS processes.
If this is indeed what Tomcat does then it is possible that never more than 21 connections were in use and the remaining 10 connections were never needed. That is, the app never needed more than 21 connections simultaneously.
It's worth noting that depending on the size of the database server hardware and how much demand other applications are putting on the database, the number of connections in this pool may be on the large side. Ideally the total number of connections to a database machine should be a small multiple of the number of hardware threads allocated to the database. Example: 48 hardware threads available to the database. Then the total number of connections to that database machine, from all apps not per pool, ideally should be less than 200 or so. If this is the only pool accessing this database machine and it has at least 5 hardware threads the pool size is fine.
There are also reasons to use the least recently returned connection so that all the connections are used more or less equally. Which is better depends on lots of things.
